# Winjs: Position certain toolbar controls to the left

Tags: html, css, winjs, windows-10-universal

I want to position certain controls on my toolbar to the left. I've somewhat achieved it but as you can see from the screenshot below, they're overlapping.

[image: Toolbar]

Here is my HTML...

```
    <div class="AudioControls" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ToolBar">
        <!--Top Level Controls-->
        <button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Command"
                data-win-options="{
                    id: 'cmdPrevTrack',
                    label: 'Previous',
                    type: 'button',
                    icon: 'previous',
                    section: 'primary',
                    priority: 1
                }" class="AudioControlsPosLeft"></button>
        <button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Command"
                data-win-options="{
                    id:'cmdPlay',
                    label: 'Play',
                    type: 'button',
                    icon: 'play',
                    section: 'primary',
                    priority: 2
                }" class="AudioControlsPosLeft"></button>
        <button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Command"
                data-win-options="{
                    id: 'cmdNextTrack',
                    label: 'Next',
                    type: 'button',
                    icon: 'next',
                    section: 'primary',
                    priority: 3
                }"></button>
        <button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Command"
                data-win-options="{
                    id: 'cmdChangeVolume',
                    label: 'Volume',
                    type: 'button',
                    icon: 'volume'
                }"></button>
        <button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Command"
                data-win-options="{
                    id: 'cmdShuffleTrackLst',
                    label: 'Shuffle',
                    type: 'button',
                    icon: 'shuffle'
                }"></button>
        <button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Command"
                data-win-options="{
                    id: 'cmdSettings',
                    label: 'Settings',
                    type: 'button',
                    icon: 'settings'
                }"></button>
```

And my CSS...

```
.AudioControls {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    color:white;
}

.AudioControlsPosLeft {
    position: absolute !important;
    left: 5px;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Technically ToolBar is designed in a such way that it automatically manages grouping of elements and their positioning in primary or secondary (overflow) areas. So whatever you are going to do will be a kind of "hacking" prescripted behavior. E.g. it is not clear how such buttons should be repositioned when there is not enough space.

If you want to have buttons on the left and buttons on the right I would recommend to just add two ToolBars:

- For the left one - add `style="direction:rtl"` to ensure buttons are aligned to the left edge.
- For the right one -- continue using what you already have.

Answer (score 0):

Toolbar Control use flex layout. And the `justify-content` property of `.win-commandingsurface-actionarea` controls the flow direction of buttons inside.

To move the buttons to the left, simply override this property in your css file:

```
.win-commandingsurface-actionarea {
    justify-content:flex-start!important;
}
```

And the buttons will be moved to left.